# Convert Variables to characters in R

Tags: r, string, character

I want to take the names of the variables in `a` and results as in `b`

```
a <- list(EURUSD,USDJPY,CADJPY)

b <- c("EURUSD", "USDJPY", "CADJPY")
```

How can I do it instead of writing it manually?

Comment: Is "a" a named list? If yes, just use `b = names(a)`

Comment: Already answered, but if you want to skip the a `a` part you can use `ls()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, R evaluates lazily, but when you assigned the list to the variable `a` the expression `list(EURUSD, USDJPY, CADJPY)` got evaluated. Unless the three objects are named and have exactly same names, it is not possible to get their names.

What you could try is parse the output of `ls()`: look for all 6 character all caps names in your namespace.

Example:

```
EURUSD <- runif(10)
USDJPY <- runif(10)
CADJPY <- runif(10)

blablabla <- 'unused variable'

currency_pairs <- ls(pattern='^[A-Z]{6}$')
print(currency_pairs)
[1] "CADJPY" "EURUSD" "USDJPY"
```

Comment: The `ls` function has a pattern argument for such cases

Comment: Bcz you commented on my post, this will not work if the pattern is not upper case

Comment: @akrun Sorry I don't understand. You can get lower case pattern like this: `'^[A-Za-z]{6}$'` if that is what you meant.

Comment: @Dmitril I meant that the object name can be anything and if the user wants to subset a particular file, then the pattern with regex might give more names because the regex used is generic

Comment: Ok then G. Grotendieck's solution may be what you need.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `substitute`

```
f1 <- function(...) {
 v1 <- sapply(as.list(substitute(list(...)))[-1], deparse)
 v2 <- unlist(strsplit(v1, "list|[(), ]"))
 v2[nzchar(v2)]
 }

f1(EURUSD)
#[1] "EURUSD"

f1(list(EURUSD, USDJPY))
#[1] "EURUSD" "USDJPY"

f1(list(EURUSD,USDJPY,CADJPY))
#[1] "EURUSD" "USDJPY" "CADJPY"
```

#### data

```
EURUSD <- 1:10
USDJPY <- 11:20
CADJPY <- 21:30
```

Comment: it returns the following error `Error in mget(a) : invalid first argument`

Answer (score 0):

We cannot create `a` and then determine the variable names that went into it by inspecting `a` itself since at the point `a` is created the variable names are lost; however, we can create a function `namify` to which is passed not `a` but `list(EURUSD, USDJPY, CADJPY)`.  In that case the function could parse the input expression and also evaluate it.

```
namify <- function(x) {
    setNames(x, sapply(substitute(x)[-1], deparse))
}

# test it
EURUSD <- USDJPY <- CADJPY <- 1
L <- namify(list(EURUSD, USDJPY, CADJPY))
```

giving this named list:

```
> L
$EURUSD
[1] 1

$USDJPY
[1] 1

$CADJPY
[1] 1
```

`names(L)` and `unname(L)` would be the names and unnamed list respectively.

Note that the preferred way to do all this really is to start with a named list in the first place.  For example, supposing that each variable is stored in a csv file in current directory:

```
csvFiles <- Sys.glob("*.csv")
L <- Map(read.csv, csvFiles)
names(L) <- sub("[.]csv$", "", names(L))   # remove .csv from names
```